# Difference between atom and elementary particle questioned

Tags: electrons, atoms, hydrogen, protons, ions

[Hydrogen ion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_ion) doesn't have one electron which clearly mean that it has only one proton..So hydrogen ion is only a proton. Am I right, please make it clear. If hydrogen ion and proton are same that how to explain the reactivity with electron?

Comment: it is not clear why you have a problem. Ion means an  atom minus at least one electron , the hydrogen atom has only one electron and a single proton as a nucleus. Deuterium also has one electron and the bare charge 1 nucleus is composed of a proton and a neutron. It is the positive charge of the proton that attracts the negative electron.

Comment: Then does it mean that hydrogen ion and proton is one and same thing? What is the fundamental difference between them?

Comment: If you're talking about hydrogen and not any of it's isotopes (deutirium, tritium) then there is no difference between a Hydrogen ion and a proton. They are the same thing.

Comment: Isn't there diff...like energy between them, one possessing more energy and other not..

Comment: the hydrogen positive ion and the proton are identically the same

Answer (score 2):

A hydrogen atom ion $H^{+}$, with an atomic mass number of A=1, charge number Z=1, is the same as a proton. A hydrogen ion thus usually just refers to a proton. Depending on context, however, you may also have a hydrogen ion which is (a) an ion of a deuterium atom, in which case it is a bound state of a neutron and a proton, with atomic mass number A=2, charge number Z=1; or you could have (b) a hydrogen molecule ion, which is $H_{2}^{+}$, which is a hydrogen molecule with one electron stripped off.

Comment: Then does it mean that if we add one elctron to the proton then it will start behaving like hydrogen atom..

Comment: If the electron-proton system gives off energy and enters a bound state, then yes, it will behave like a hydrogen atom.

Comment: Then it will clearly mean that alchemistry was possible.. We can simply convert one element to other by taking protons away or adding some protons..Doesn't it sound weird??

Comment: Yes, you can convert an atom of one element into an atom of another by adding the appropriate number of protons and neutrons to the nucleus. For example, you could start with a hydrogen nucleus (A=1, Z=1) and add two protons and four neutrons to make a lithium nucleus (A=7, Z=3). But this is extremely hard!! Protons are positively charged, and so two protons repel each other. To introduce another proton into the nucleus is very hard and requires a lot of energy to overcome the repulsion. Thus it is not easy to convert one element into another.

Comment: To continue: Yes, it can be done, typically in a particle accelerator. This is how most of the elements with atomic charge numbers Z>100 were produced. See this link (http://science.howstuffworks.com/dictionary/chemistry-terms/transmutation-info.htm) for more details.

Comment: To give another example, if you put two hydrogen atoms $H$ together, you get a hydrogen molecule $H_{2}$. It still has two nuclei. You have performed a chemical reaction. To convert two protons and two neutrons together to form a single helium nucleus, you need to perform a nuclear reaction, to join them into a single nucleus. The energy scales are very different.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7610/what-is-the-difference-between-a-neutron-and-hydrogen... please check this link..There is something other explained..

Comment: I don't see the problem - the answer described there is compatible with mine.